# Detecting scale bar in image - feature detection or pattern recognition

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, ocr

What would be the best method for finding scale bars in images in order to automate scaling pixels to actual length measurements?
I have found some work done on finding bar codes, which may be similar, but they appear to be using contrast differences along horizontal and vertical cross section of the image, which I don't thin would work all that well for finding scale bars.
Would this be best achieved using neural networks or some sort of pattern recognition, or could I get away with doing some image processing which would provide more sound logic?
I am very new to image processing.
I assume most people have seen a microscope image with a scale bar, but just in case here are some example of what I mean:

[image: some scale bar image]
This would return 100 nanometers and whatever pixel length the scale bar is.

[image: another scale bar image]
This would return 500 nanometers and whatever pixel length the scale bar is.

[image: another guy]
This would return 5 nanometers and whatever the pixel length of the scale bar is.

I am starting to work with OpenCV on this problem, but I am open to suggestions for languages, packages, or algorithms.  Does anyone have any ideas regarding this task in image processing?

Comment: If you know the position inside the image of where the data you are interested at (amount of nm) is located, then the problem becomes quite trivial. Is this the case?

Comment: My hope was to create a solution that could be applied to any image with a scale bar in it, which would automatically detect the scale bar no matter where it is.  However, a certain piece of software or equipment may have a starting location on the image.  The scale bar will change sizes though so it wont be the same pixels every time.

Comment: The problem is that the scale bar is so different (color, shape, size, location) on all of these images that at some point, if you decide that you really want a robust solution, you are going to start using some sort of template matching to recognize known microscopic images.

Comment: Would support vector machines or some type of object recognition work for that? Most of the stuff I have seen on svm has been for simple stuff and classification of an entire image. Is there a way to pick up features based on svm applied to regions within an image?

Comment: On this field, you will only know for sure if you try. Can't help you further than this, but there are experts here that might be able to give you some hints. Good Luck!

Comment: Ĺearning methods (svm, nn etc) need good fearures to work. Dont think that stuff like hog will work here. Maybe featues like line direction, distance to image border, existance of a digit etc. Or haar stuff?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution for this problem would be from an OCR point of view, which is almost a solved problem. For this you need to look where patterns like nm, mm, cm, etc are located in the image. Once you have the location of the scale characters, the assumption would be that the scale bar would be located at a nearby location and would be sufficiently distinguishable from other horizontal line segments. There can be two cases:

1. The scale bar is located on a textureless background. In this case the problem should not be very hard as it is possible to search for a horizontal line segment. How do you find a line segment? Do edge detection with hysteresis, compute a straightness metric (you can define it yourself).
2. The scale bar is located over a texture, say Google images. In such a case, you might need to fit a line (after thresholding edge weights) based on RANSAC so that you can prune away spurious candidates which do not correspond to a straight line. There might even be lines in the background. At this time, you can chose the line segment with 0/90 angle (depending on the orientation of the characters) which is nearest to the characters in the scale. Another good assumption would be that lines on the scale bar would have stronger edges than background lines.

I have a feeling that this problem can be solved purely with vision without much learning involving data. Of course, if the OCR system uses some inbuilt learning that may be part of it, however for getting the scale bar, a computer vision system should be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer. I had not heard of RANSAC, and I hadn't thought of having a straightness metric, which will help, so you have given me some stuff to look into.